# PySpark UDF of MapType with mixed value type

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an JSON input like this

```
    {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 5
      },
      "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "list": {
          "10": {
            "id": 10
          },
          "11": {
            "id": 11
          },
          "20": {
            "id": 20
          }
        }
      },
      "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "key": "a"
      }
    }
```

I need to merge the 3 columns and extract the needed values for each column, and this is the output I need:

```
    {
      "out": {
        "1": 5,
        "2": [10, 11, 20],
        "3": "a"
      }
    }
```

I tried to create a UDF to transform these 3 columns into 1, but I could not figure how to define MapType() with mixed value types - `IntegerType()`, `ArrayType(IntegerType())` and `StringType()` respectively.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MapType()` is used for (key, value) pairs definitions not for nested data frames. What you're looking for is `StructType()`

You can load it directly using `createDataFrame` but you'd have to pass a schema, so this way is easier:

```py
import json

data_json = {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 5
      },
      "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "list": {
          "10": {
            "id": 10
          },
          "11": {
            "id": 11
          },
          "20": {
            "id": 20
          }
        }
      },
      "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "key": "a"
      }
    }
a=[json.dumps(data_json)]
jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(a)
df = spark.read.json(jsonRDD)
df.printSchema()

    root
     |-- 1: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
     |-- 2: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- list: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- 10: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- 11: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- 20: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- 3: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
```

Now to access nested dataframes. Note that column "2" is more nested than the other ones:

```py
nested_cols = ["2"]
cols = ["1", "3"]
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df = df.select(
    cols + [psf.array(psf.col(c + ".list.*")).alias(c) for c in nested_cols]
)
df = df.select(
    [df[c].id.alias(c) for c in df.columns]
)

    root
     |-- 1: long (nullable = true)
     |-- 3: long (nullable = true)
     |-- 2: array (nullable = false)
     |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

It's not exactly your final output since you want it nested in an `"out"` column:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.select(psf.struct("*").alias("out")).printSchema()

    root
     |-- out: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |-- 1: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- 3: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- 2: array (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

Finally back to JSON:

```py
df.toJSON().first()

    '{"1":1,"3":3,"2":[10,11,20]}'
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this, but structure "2" could have nullable items, such as some records might have only 10.

And if possible, is there any way to make flattening of structure "2" dynamic, regardless of what elements in the nested?

`"2": { "id": 2, "list": { "10": { "id": 10 } } }`

Thanks!

Comment: I tried `col("2.list.*").getField("id")` but I guess `getField()` does not work with `*` as the error is `u"Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'unresolvedextractvalue';"`

Comment: I have updated my answer so it is dynamic. The fact that "2" has nullable items doesn't change anything.

Comment: When you use `*` it flattens the structure creating multiple columns, so when you try to access `id` you're actually telling it to access the sub column of multiple columns at once, which is not possible

Comment: Hope this helps, don't forget to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 4):

You need to define resulting type of the UDF using `StructType`, not the `MapType`, like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

udf_result = StructType([
    StructField('1', IntegerType()),
    StructField('2', ArrayType(StringType())),
    StructField('3', StringType())
])
```

Comment: Gotcha, that works. Just wonder if there is anyway of achieving this without UDF?